# Save and detect a particular shake gesture pattern iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

In my project i have implemented the shake gesture in iphone. I want to save a particular shake pattern(say, shake like the word "S") from user and i need to invoke event only on the particular pattern. Is this possible in iphone ? If possible, can anyone guide me with some reference please ??

Comment: Hey I am in same situation. Can you please guide me on this? I want to detect 'z' motion

Comment: @vivek : sorry bro.. i have left that R&D..

Answer (score 3):

Go through  [Core motion programming guide](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=core%20motion%20reference%20programming%20guide&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FEventHandling%2FConceptual%2FEventHandlingiPhoneOS%2FMotionEvents%2FMotionEvents.html&ei=2A71ULX2FoKErQfQsIGIDg&usg=AFQjCNH0dAlFO3QE_DLu48pVITtXU49g3g&bvm=bv.41018144,d.bmk) and [Core motion framework reference](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=core%20motion%20reference%20programming%20guide&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FCoreMotion%2FReference%2FCoreMotion_Reference%2F_index.html&ei=2A71ULX2FoKErQfQsIGIDg&usg=AFQjCNHffaocOSD5CGeO00m74cKywRZ00g&bvm=bv.41018144,d.bmk). and understand the iPhone device motion apis, you will able to implement your custom motion event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reference you have given is some what hard to understand. is there any other working samples demos on this concept ??

Answer (score 2):

Seconding pradeepa, you will need to learn to use Core Motion and the UIAccelerometer APIs – start with the ["Motion Events" chapter in the Event Handling Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html).

For your custom shape-motion recognizer, you will need to evaluate the movement of the device in (x/y/z-) space over time.

Answer (score 2):

This project may help, [AcceleroMusic](https://github.com/govind678/AcceleroMusic).
You need to define x,y,z to map your particular shake pattern("S" shake).

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think from [Hear](http://www.iphoneexamples.com/) for shaking effect on iphone,
or you can use

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation; 
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
theAnimation.duration=1;
theAnimation.repeatCount=2;
theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-60];
[view.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

Hope It  will help you